# How can I change the DWORD value of a registry key via python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.8, winreg

I am trying to make a script that disables cmd. Here is my script:

```py
import winreg
registry_key = winreg.OpenKey(winreg.HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\System", 0, winreg.KEY_WRITE)
winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, "DisableCMD", 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, "1")
```

But I get

```py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\username\winregg.py", line 3, in <module>
    winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, "DisableCMD", 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, "1")
ValueError: Could not convert the data to the specified type.
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Are you running 32- or 64-bit Python on 64-bit Windows? Because if you are, things can get tricky…

Comment: Are you sure the last parameter is "1" and not just 1?  Googling around I see examples where it isn't quoted that claim to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
winreg.SetValueEx(registry_key, "DisableCMD", 0, winreg.REG_DWORD, 1)
```